# JavaFX-8 - How to get the row count of a TableView?

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, rowcount, tablecell

How is it possible to get the number of rows of a `TableView` in a `TableCell`? I tried `.getTableRow()`, but that isn't what I need. I need it to find out, if the `TableCell` is the last Cell in the `TableView`.
Or is there another way to figure this out?

regards

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the solution on my own. I'm very ashamed. :-)

```
getTableView().getItems().size()
```

That's it.

Comment: `getItems` wasn't easy for me to find either :-(    looking for `getRows()` or `getRowModel()` or `getRowCollection()`.